# Is it possible to rewrite URL by first capital letter?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to make that .htaccess looks for first capital letter in the URL?

For example:

```
example.com/?country=United-Kingdom
```

should be rewritten to:

```
example.com/United-Kingdom
```

BUT

```
example.com/?page=somepage
```

should be rewritten to:

```
example.com/somepage
```

Basically I want htaccess to take action for the string which starts with first capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /?country=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

These two rules will take requests like: `http://example.com/United-Kingdom` and internally rewrite them to: `/?country=United-Kingdom` while requests like `http://example.com/somepage` get internally rewritten to `/?page=somepage` assuming that pages can't have capital letters.

To redirect the browser to show the non-query string URL's, you'll need:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(index\.php)?\?(page|country)=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%3 [L,R=301]
```